# QGIS server crashes with GetPrint request

Tags: wms, pdf, qgis-server, apache, getprint

I'm running QGIS server on Ubuntu 14.04 and until now it worked without problems.

Now I want to create print composer output, [GetProjectSettings request](http://217.126.85.135/cgi-bin/seguimiento_gis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetProjectSettings) shows composer template "plantilla".

I request a print output like this:

```
http://217.126.85.135/cgi-bin/seguimiento_gis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetPrint&TEMPLATE=plantilla&CRS=EPSG:4326&map0:EXTENT=34.5987,-10.9848,44.5071,4.59801&map0:ROTATION=0&FORMAT=pdf&DPI=300
```

But fcgid crashes with a coredump:

```
mod_fcgid: error reading data, FastCGI server closed connection
```

Update: Using a more simple template works and [GetPrint request](http://217.126.85.135/cgi-bin/seguimiento_gis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetPrint&TEMPLATE=plantilla2&map0:LAYERS=municipios_etrs89&map0:EXTENT=34.5987,-10.9848,44.5071,4.59801&FORMAT=pdf&DPI=300) gives a valid response. Seems to be a problem of texts and HTML in the template "plantilla". Any idea how to debug this error and get to the roots of the problem with the template?